# Symfony and plain php autoload class

Tags: php, symfony

I have app with old code - plain php and new code - Symfony. And when in old code call class symfony autoloader, maybe, intercepts class, how told Symfony to call exctly needed class

I have `app/old/core/classes/Locale.php` from old code, without name space and 
`app/src/AppBundle/Entity/Locale.php` from new code, this is entity with name space

and in old code I call static function Locale from old code, but Symfony call entity, of course entity LOcale dont have this static function and I have error

```
class Page
{
    function replacePageTags($replace_arr)
    {
        // set brases for keys
        $braced_arr = Array();

        foreach($replace_arr as $key => $value) {
            $braced_arr["{".$key."}"] = $value;
        }

        //this I have error 
        $this->content = Locale::replaceTags($this->content, $braced_arr);
    }
}
```

error message:

> Attempted to call an undefined method named "replaceTags" of class "Locale".

whe I add include Locale to class Page

```
include('Locale.php');

class Page
{
```

have error

> Error: Cannot declare class Locale, because the name is already in use

But when I add to entity `static function replaceTags($text, $replace_arr)` still have error, maybe Symfony call another Locale, but I need call Locale from old functionality, how can I do this ?

maybe this because in composer in autoload I have

```
    "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "": "src/"
    }
```

but old code not in src or I dont know

In another developer have not this problem, I have php version 7.0.14, they have 7.0.8, maybe I need low some ph destriction, I don't know (
How to call exectly needed class in old code or fix this problem?

Comment: Please add the actual error message to the question. Do you have [intl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.intl.php)  extension enabled?

Comment: error message `Attempted to call an undefined method named "replaceTags" of class "Locale".` because symfony call another calss with name Locale, I think

Comment: So what about the extension? Do you confirm `php -m | grep intl` returns nothing?

Comment: @AlexBlex I don't think this is linked to symfony Locale, he has custom classes

Comment: @Alex Blex `intl` I have intl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Page` class uses [`\Locale`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.locale.php) from [intl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.intl.php) extension.

The only option you have is to disable the extension as the legacy (namespaceless) code is not compatible with it due to class name collision.

Comment: how to disable extension ?

Comment: it depends how you installed it. `pecl uninstall intl`, `apt-get remove php5-intl` etc.

Comment: If you can find something like `intl.ini` in php configs, e.g. `/etc/php5/mods-available`, you can comment it out liek `; extension=intl.ini`

Answer (score 0):

If your old Library does not have namespace, you can use [MapClassLoader](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/class_loader/map_class_loader.html) to do a mapping.

```
require_once '/path/to/src/Symfony/Component/ClassLoader/MapClassLoader.php';

$mapping = array(
    'Foo' => '/path/to/Foo',
    'Bar' => '/path/to/Bar',
);

$loader = new MapClassLoader($mapping);

$loader->register();
```

You can do it automatically on your old code by using [the class map generator](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/class_loader/class_map_generator.html).
This way you could have a custom namespace like `Legacy\Class` for all your old classes

Comment: If it was the problem, I'd recommend to use composer to map classes instead.